# How to deal with ThreadPool and member variables?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, variables, member

I am a bit new to ThreadPool in .NET. I was wondering, if I can only send one object to my callback method, how am I able to access the class member variable to call its methods?  (see customClass in CallBack())

And how would I load the data from customClass? Do I pass the customClass to a different CallBack method? is this approach alright?

As you can see it is a bit of lack of experience, so any tips along the way would really be appreciated.

Thank you,
Kave

```
class Program
           {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    CustomClass customClass = new CustomClass();

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CallBack, "Hello"); 


                Console.Read();
            }

            private static void CallBack(object state)
            {
                customClass.SaveData(state.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    CustomClass customClass = new CustomClass();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => CallBack(customClass, "Hello")); 
    Console.Read();
  }

  private static void CallBack(CustomClass custom, string text)
  {
    customClass.SaveData(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice sample, but the call to SaveData should really be SaveData(text) -- just a copy/paste leftover, obviously ;-)

Comment: wow very nice example! With .NET 3.5 there is no need for CallBack methods having object as parameter anymore is this correct?

I would also highly appreciate a .NET 2.0 solution to this problem, so I know both ways. Any idea?

Comment: Just had an idea, would that be the way its done in .NET 2.0 world?

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { CallBack(customClass, "World"); });

Comment: @Kave: See the article linked in my answer. Instead of using a lambda expression, use an anonymous method.

@Stefan: Why bother with the "Callback" method at all? Just write: x => customClass.SaveData("Hello")

Comment: @Kave: Yes, that's the way you do it in C# 2. Note that you can use lambda expressions with C# 3 even if you're targeting .NET 2.0. It's a language feature, not a framework feature.

Comment: @Jon

But in order to compile the code .NET 3.5 must be installed, isn't it? I don't think you can compile lamda expressions on dev environments with .NET 2.0 only.  regarding anonymous method, wouldn'y a delegate be doing the same job? (I admit I dont know about anonymous methods yet) :)

Comment: @Kave, yes, you need Visual Studio 2008 or the .NET 3.5 SDK as a developer.  Your users only would need .NET 2.0, though.

Comment: One more question came up, what if my Callback method is returning an integer.  How would the caller from main method get that integer back?

Comment: @Kave: Anonymous methods are just another way of creating delegates. They're like lambdas but slightly clunkier.

Comment: @Kave:
1. in .Net 2.0, I think you need to cast the delegate, or use the new operator: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)delegate { CallBack(customClass, "World"); }); I'm not even sure if this would work. x => Foo() actually generate a delegate with an argument x, that is not used in this case. It's this "object state" argument that is required.

2. You can't return anything from a thread. It is an asynchronous call, isn't it? But of course you can return values from lambdas.

Comment: @Jon Thanks.
@Stefan, also thanks for explanation. Your delegate is correct and would work. Regarding 2) you are right. And yet I think only the Backgroundworker can do this though. Amazing no one takes that poor Backgroundworker seriously, yet it is kind of powerful. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use a [closure](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) to capture all the variables you want (i.e. use an anonymous method or a lambda expression). You need to be careful about exactly what's captured if you're using a loop, but it's handier than passing through an object and having to cast it back to the right type etc.

Comment: To clarify, the reason care needs to be taken in loops with closure is addressed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-captured-variable-in-loop

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said: If `CustomClass` is under your control and asynchronously invoking `SaveData` is a common use case, you could think about providing a `SaveDataAsync` method:

```
class CustomClass {

    public void SaveDataAsync(string path) {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => this.SaveData(path));
    }

    public void SaveData(string path) {
        ...
    }
}
```

See [the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx).